# как хранить шаблоны отпечатки пальцев модуля arduino в сервере

Tags: arduino, fingerprint

модуль распознавания отпечатков пальцев **arduino** хранит шаблоны в своей **flash** памяти,
а я хочу хранить их в **SD Card** или на сервере для дальнейшего проверки на возможность доступа

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема? С fingerprint получаете картинку и положите куда вам нужно!

Comment: А потом как организовать поиск по картинкам

Comment: У fingerprint ограничение для храниние шаблонов

Comment: программно сравнивать картинки, либо на сервере либо в ардуино